# Python: how to skip the repeated lines in an input file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am reading from a file and I want to read each line alone, since each 3rd line in the output has to be a combination of the previous 2 lines. This is a small example:

```
Input:

<www.example.com/apple> <Anything>
<www.example.com/banana> <Anything>

Output:

<www.example.com/apple> <Anything>
<www.example.com/banana> <Anything>
<Apple> <Banana>
```

If any of the lines is repeated or if it is an empty line, then I do not want to process it, I want to get only 2 different lines each time.

This is a part of my real input:

```
<http://catalog.data.gov/bread> <http://dbpedia.org> 
<http://catalog.data.gov/bread> <http://dbpedia.org>
<http://catalog.data.gov/bread> <http://dbpedia.org> 
<http://catalog.data.gov/bread> <http://dbpedia.org> 

<http://catalog.data.gov/roll> <http://dbpedia.org>
<http://catalog.data.gov/roll> <http://dbpedia.org>
```

In this case I want the output to be like this:

```
 <http://catalog.data.gov/bread> <http://dbpedia.org> 
 <http://catalog.data.gov/roll> <http://dbpedia.org>
 <bread> <roll>
```

This is my code:

```
file = open('rdfs.txt')
for id, line in enumerate(file):
        if id % 2 == 0:
            if line.isspace():
                continue
            line1 = line.split()
            sub_line1, rel_line1 = line1[0], line1[1]
            sub_line1 = sub_line1.lstrip("<").rstrip(">")
            print(sub_line1)

        else:
            if line.isspace():
                continue
            line2 = line.split()
            sub_line2, rel_line2 = line2[0], line2[1]
            sub_line2 = sub_line2.lstrip("<").rstrip(">")
            print(sub_line2)
```

It is working perfectly, but I am getting all the lines, how to add if the second line is equal to the line before then skip all the lines until you find a new different line.

The output I am getting now:

```
http://catalog.data.gov/bread
http://catalog.data.gov/bread
http://catalog.data.gov/roll
http://catalog.data.gov/roll
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a `set()` and named it `line_seen` that will hold all seen lines, and check on every new line if it in the `lines_seen` or not and add it to your check:

Your code should looks like:

```
file = open('rdfs.txt')
lines_seen = set() # holds lines already seen
for id, line in enumerate(file):
    if line not in lines_seen: # not a duplicate
        lines_seen.add(line)
        if id % 2 == 0:
            if line.isspace():
                continue
            line1 = line.split()
            sub_line1, rel_line1 = line1[0], line1[1]
            sub_line1 = sub_line1.lstrip("<").rstrip(">")
            print(sub_line1)

        else:
            if line.isspace():
                continue
            line2 = line.split()
            sub_line2, rel_line2 = line2[0], line2[1]
            sub_line2 = sub_line2.lstrip("<").rstrip(">")
            print(sub_line2)
```

Comment: Glad to help you.